# Build a GO program in Windows

Tags: go

I have found an interesting program in the **language of Go**. This is the first time I work with this language and I dont know much of it.

Basically [it is a network bandwidth speedtest.](https://github.com/zpeters/speedtest)

**The program works verry well**, I just would like to modify its output a little. So I have to edit the source **and rebuild the project** to get the update .exe file.

[The wiki of the project says:](https://github.com/zpeters/speedtest/wiki/Build-Instructions)

**Building speedtest**

1. Clone/build speedtest go get github.com/zpeters/speedtest
2. cd ~/go/bin/code>
3. ./speedtest

I did step 1. but I don't know what to do with step 2. ? What is it ? What is "~" means and what is "code>" ?

Also is "./" means running a shell script file? I work in Windows. Can somebody please help me to compile this Go program?

**E D I T:**

The `src` contains **3 packages:**

- github.com
- golang.org
- gopkg.in

**How should I compile?**

If I try:

```
go install speedtest
```

I got

> can't load package: package speedtest: cannot find package "speedtest" in any of:
>
> C:\go\src\speedtest (from $GOROOT)
>
> C:\gonetwork\src\speedtest (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Isn't `GOBIN` already in your PATH? Have you just tried running the program again?

Comment: @JimB Its in my PATH. I have already built successfully a hello world Go program. But I cannot build this one with the method given in the hello world example

Comment: I don't understand. running `go get github.com/zpeters/speedtest` already built the binary and put it in GOBIN.

Comment: re: your last edit, "speedtest" isn't a package, the package is "github.com/zpeters/speedtest"

Comment: @JimB Add this as an answer so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your message line:

> C:\gonetwork\src\speedtest (from $GOPATH)

suggests that your GOPATH is set to c:\Gonetwork.

Do it like this then, open a command prompt.

```
c:
cd \GoNetwork\src
go get github.com/zpeters/speedtest
```

When it completes:

```
c:\GoNetwork\bin\speedtest.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as you have been able to execute `go get github.com/zpeters/speedtest` with no error, you already have your code in your `$GOPATH` and the binary in $GOBIN, the only thing you need to modify it is go to its location, in your case, according to your output it should be something like:

```
cd C:\gonetwork\src\speedtest\github.com\zpeters\speedtest
```

Once you are there, and modified the code to your needs, you only need to run `go install github.com/zpeters/speedtest`